# Matlab: Find values of a matrix between desired bounds

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix sorted in ascending order.

```
S = 25;
RT = zeros(S,2);
  for i = 1:S;
    for j = 1:i;
    R = i *j;
    T = R + j;
    RT(j,:) = [R T];
    end

  end
sortRT = sortrows(RT, [1 2]);
disp(sortRT);
```

I want to find the sortRT elements which values is lower than 500 (for R) and 490 (for T) per column and place these values inside a matrix. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with 'find elements per column'? Do you want to copy rows/elements where `R<500` and/or `T<490`? Please clearly specify what you want. An example is always a good start.

Comment: Yes i want to copy elements which fulfill those criteria to a new matrix. @GuntherStruyf your response is exactly the answer was looking for. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
idx = find(sortRT(:,1)<500 & sortRT(:,2)<490)

idx' = 

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
```

These are the rows where both `R<500` and `T<490`. You can of course separate these two:

```
idxR500 = find(sortRT(:,1)<500);
idxT490 = find(sortRT(:,2)<490);
```

If you're just going to copy elements or rows, then find isn't even necessary and you can use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html):

```
R500 = sortRT(find(sortRT(:,1)<500) , 1);
```

is the same as

```
R500 = sortRT(sortRT(:,1)<500 , 1);
```

This copies elements of the first column, if you want to copy the whole row, use the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
R500 = sortRT(sortRT(:,1)<500 , :);
```

Comment: Clean and instructive answer. Thank you.